# Android custom spinner styles further

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

first I want to say this is not creating same thread for custom spinner styles.
In my application I like to show a string and a image at the spinner
But when I go through the documentation I notice only following constructors.

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId)
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
Constructor
```

So I can initially have one object. that is can be string ,image and etc.

But I wan to keep both string and a image.

I know how to show image and a string after spinner is expanded.

I think my problem is clear.Is there way to handle this??

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/ . Might help

Comment: `mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(CustomSpinnerDemo.this, R.layout.row, strings));` here it passes only sting array. I need to passe two objects